How to load additional data in Sveltekits load function
In sveltekit, a +page.svelte renders the data that was loaded using a +page.ts load function.
But what if there is a Button on the page like "more data..." to load additional data.
How to tell the load function to run again, but with different parameters?
This may work with url parameters, I guess, but what if you do not want to use these url parameters?
What I did until now, was having the data loading completely inside the +page.svelte, what was quite easy because I just hold the state of:
const top = 10
let skip = $state(0)
let data = $state([])

async function loadData(top, skip) {
   //...
   data = [data..., newdata]
}

And when a button is clicked, it increases the skip and this triggers the loadData.
But this does not seem to be the Sveltekit way, I guess.
I have no idea, how to do this with such a load function.
I could also load the additional data inside the +page.svelte, but this would then maybe conflict with the load function. I would have to merge the data from the load function with the data loaded in the actual +page.svelte and if the load function gets invalidated it may be inconsistent.
Is there any best practice for that?
There should be a lot of scenarios like this, where the initial data loading is not enough and a page has to load some more data at a later point in time.

I think you can create api routes, I can't confirm if this is the best practice (myself also beginner), but it certainly looks a better approach than loading the whole data on first page load.
Following code is taken from here
// routes/random_number/+server.js

export function GET() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}

<script>
    //routes/+page.svelte
    /** @type {number} */
    let number;

    async function roll() {
        const response = await fetch('/random_number');
        number = await response.json();
    }
</script>

<button on:click={roll}>Roll the dice</button>

{#if number !== undefined}
    <p>You rolled a {number}</p>
{/if}


Hi. But what would this change regarding my problem? Since this is not in a load function anymore it does not provide the data aggregation and automatic refresh functionality anymore. Also I have to do this get requests still manually in the +page.svelte I guess.

AFAIk, the load data function is called on page refresh, which seems like an overkill just to load additional data. You can think of these requests as pagination, i.e. do not fetch the data that is already fetched. Loading whole data on page refresh will increase page load time, plus you have to refresh the page every time you need the data.

This answer was more focused to answer this part: "But what if there is a Button on the page like "more data..." to load additional data.". Ofcourse you will have to do some data munging to show the correct data.


This may work with url parameters, I guess, but what if you do not want to use these url parameters?

If you don't want to use URL parameters, then you don't implement a proper website, and shouldn't use SvelteKit at all, but a framework designed for your needs. The web is built on that the URL identifies the resources shown on the screen, so bookmarking works, and sending the URL to a friend works, etc., so why wouldn't you want this functionality?
There are of course workarounds you can use instead of a URL parameter, but the best practice is to use a URL parameter, as the web is intended to be used.

How will that work? Let's say the query parameters are top=10&skip=20. The load function would just load 10 items, but what is with the rest? And how would this help when sending the url around? You would have to use skip=0&top=30, meaning to load always all items again, even when you already have most of them. I haven't seen such an approach for "load more data" lists that use query parameters for that...

Yes, what you describe would be the default behavior you need to implement to make it work also for users that have client-side JS disabled. If you then have the time to be fancy, you can after that add some client-side JS code to improve it for those that have client-side JS enabled, i.e. listen for clicks on the more data... button, manually update the URI without making SvelteKit run the load() function again, and then send a REST API request to only fetch the resources that are missing, and then add them to your resources array in your component.

And I agree that most websites don't do it like this, but that doesn't mean they do the right thing. I imagine their developers don't deem it worth it to do all this extra work, so they skip it, and don't care about building proper websites. I also don't think it worth it to write all this extra code to get it to work, so I would instead simply go with the traditional approach to only show the resources on page X (it works good enough IMO), or simply load all resources from page 1 to page X (if you later discover performance problems, then optimize it, or redesign it).

I found a good example for that scenario. It uses "isDataRequest" that I didn't know of. This avoids making a full data request each time: https://www.sveltelab.dev/nvvn05skycdj2n9

This approaches work well for CMS like websites. But for complex SPAs, I don't think it is always possible. In this case, features that SvelteKit provides, e.g., routing and API handlers, can still be pretty useful.
